# Why does this nested for loop count negative columns incorrectly?

Tags: python, pandas, nested-loops

I wrote a nested for-loop that should count the number of negative values in each column in my dataframe, and produce a dataframe that has the column name and number of negative values.

It runs without error, but after doing some validation i found that it is not counting accurately. It is missing a lot of negative values.

Could anybody explain what is causing this to miss some negative values? I am already looking for another method but i just want to know why.

Here is the code:

```
input_negative_vars_dict = {}
for col in input_colnames:
    count = 0
    for row in input_df[col]:
        if row < 0:
            count +=1
        else:
            break
    input_negative_vars_dict[col] = count

#convert dict to data frame and export
input_negative_vars_df = pd.DataFrame(list(input_negative_vars_dict.items()), columns = ['colname', 'count_input'])
```

Comment: It's missing a lot of values because you're breaking out of the inner loop once you get any non-negative value. Remove the else: break part and it will count all negative values

Answer (score 1):

To resolve your issue, remove the `else: break`

The `break` will preventing counting negative numbers after counting a non-negative number:

```py
for col in input_colnames:
    count = 0
    for row in input_df[col]:
        if row < 0:
            count +=1
    input_negative_vars_dict[col] = count
```

Answer (score 1):

Why would you use a loop to perform this operation?

If you use pandas, you should vectorize:

```
input_colnames = ['A', 'B', 'C']

out = (df[input_colnames].lt(0).sum()
       # the line below is optional
       .rename_axis(index='col_name').reset_index(name='count')
      )
```

Output:

```
  col_name  count
0        A      3
1        B      2
2        C      0
```

Used input:

```
   A  B  C  D  E
0 -1  0  1 -2 -1
1  0 -1  0 -1  2
2 -2  2  1  0  0
3  0  0  0 -1 -1
4 -1 -1  2  0  0
```

Just for the sake of commenting your original approach, note that you could simplify your loop to:

```
input_negative_vars_dict = {}
for col in input_colnames:
    input_negative_vars_dict[col] = 0
    for row in input_df[col]:
        input_negative_vars_dict[col] += row < 0
```

Or:

```
input_negative_vars_dict = {col: sum(input_df[col]<0) for col in input_colnames}
```